# How to get a (Ruby) DataMapper custom type to work?

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I have a `SchoolDay` class that represents a school day: it can tell you the date, the semester, the term, the week, and the day. It can generate a string like "Sem1 13A Fri". To store these objects in the database, I want them serialized as a string.

Here is my DataMapper custom type code. I've sort of scraped ideas from the code in dm-types because (disappointingly) there is no real documentation for creating custom types. Sorry it's long.

```
module DataMapper
  class Property
    class SchoolDay < DataMapper::Property::String

      #load_as ::SchoolRecord::DomainObjects::SchoolDay
      # Commented out: the 'load_as' method is not found

      def load(value)
        # Take a string from the database and load it. We need a calendar!
        val = case value
        when ::String then calendar.schoolday(value)
        when ::SR::DO::SchoolDay then value
        else
          # fail
        end
      end

      def dump(value)
        # Store a SchoolDay value into the database as a string.
        case value
        when SR::DO::SchoolDay
          sd = value
          "Sem#{sd.semester} #{sd.weekstr} #{sd.day}"
        when ::String
          value
        else
          # fail
        end
      end

      def typecast(value)
        # I don't know what this is supposed to do -- that is, when and why it
        # is called -- but I am aping the behaviour of the Regexp custom type,
        # which, like this one, stores as a String and loads as something else.
        load(value)
      end

      # private methods calendar() and error_message() omitted
    end
  end
end
```

This code works for *reading* from the (SQLite) database, but not for *creating* new rows. The error message is:

```
Schoolday must be of type String
```

The code that defines the DataMapper resource and tries to create the record is:

```
class LessonDescription
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,          Serial
  property :schoolday,   SchoolDay  # "Sem1 3A Fri"
  property :class_label, String     # "10"
  property :period,      Integer    # (0..6), 0 being before school
  property :description, Text       # "Completed yesterday's worksheet. hw:(4-07)"
end

# ...

ld = LessonDescription.create(
  schoolday:    @schoolday,
  class_label:  @class_label,
  period:       @period,
  description:  description
)
```

Here is the code for the Regexp datamapper type in the dm-types library.  It's so simple!

```
module DataMapper
  class Property
    class Regexp < String
      load_as ::Regexp                          # NOTE THIS LINE

      def load(value)
        ::Regexp.new(value) unless value.nil?
      end

      def dump(value)
        value.source unless value.nil?
      end

      def typecast(value)
        load(value)
      end

    end
  end
end
```

For some reason, I cannot use the `load_as` line in my code.

To summarise: I am trying to create a custom type that translates between a SchoolDay (domain object) and a String (database representation). The translation is easy, and I've copied the code structure primarily from the DataMapper Regexp type. But when I try to save a SchoolDay, it complains that I'm not giving it a string. Frustratingly, I can't use the "load_as" method that the built-in and custom types *all* use, even though I have the latest gem. I can't find the "load_as" method defined anywhere in the source code for DataMapper, either. But it's called!

Sorry for the ridiculous length. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as would a pointer to a guide for creating these things that I have somehow missed.

Comment: You should accept the answer below (by clicking the check mark next to it), since it solved your issue. This lets others with the same problem know that it works.

Answer (score 9):

It seems that the current code of dm-types at github hasn't made it to any official release -- that's why `load_as` doesn't work in your example. But try to add this method:

```
module DataMapper
  class Property
    class SchoolDay < DataMapper::Property::String

      def custom?
        true
      end

    end
  end
end
```

That's working here.

Comment: **Thank you very much, @Adiel**. My code is working now. That's the first time I've heard of the "custom?" method.